# How to search and Delete in a Linked List

Tags: java, linked-list

I'm having a bit trouble with a little java activity that deals with searching and deleting a Linked List.

Here are the problems:

- add a menu to method main to handle adding to head, deleting from the head and displaying a linked listed.
- Then add a menu selection for deleting a particular element in the list and deleting it (so prompt the user for a string to delete - and then find it in the linked list and delete that element from the list).

Here are the classes:

```
public class LLNode {

    private String data;
    private LLNode next;

    public LLNode() {
        this.data = null;
        this.next = null;
    }
    public LLNode (String newData) {
        this.data = (newData);
        this.next = null;
    }
    public void updateNode (LLNode nextOne) {
        this.next = nextOne;
    }
    public String toString () {
        return  this.data;
    }
    public LLNode getNext() {
        return this.next;
    }
}


public class LList {

    private LLNode head;

    public LList() {
        head = null;
    }
    public void addAtHead (String newData) {
        LLNode newNode = new LLNode (newData);
        newNode.updateNode(head);
        head = newNode;
    }

    public void display() {
        LLNode temp = head;
        while (temp != null) {
            System.out.println (temp);
            temp = temp.getNext();
        }
    }

    public LLNode deleteAtHead ( ) {
        LLNode removedOne = head;
        head = head.getNext();
        return removedOne;
    }

}

public class LinkedListExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LList list = new LList();

        list.addAtHead("Bob");
        list.addAtHead("Tom");
        System.out.println("The list is ");
        list.display();

        LLNode removedOne = list.deleteAtHead();
        System.out.println("After delete, the list new is ");
        list.display();
        System.out.println("The one that was deleted is..." + removedOne);


    }

}
```

Comment: What problem are you having?

Comment: What did you try ? We are not here to make your exercise ;)

Comment: What's the exact problem? Your code looks okay, except that the `deleteAtHead` and `addAtHead` methods could benefit from a null-check.
I assume this code is homework, since java has a builtin `LinkedList`.

Comment: Those are not problems, those are assignments. We're not doing your homework.

Answer (score 0):

1. For creating a menu I would recommend using a while loop. You want to use some sort of scanner that checks for valid input and checks for the input of the menu.

{

```
public void main(String[] args) {
string input;

Scanner n = new Scanner(System.in);
while (!(input.equals("exit")) {

System.out.println("menu item 1");
System.out.println("menu item 2");
System.out.println("etc"); 

input = n.nextLine();
switch (input) {
case "menu 1": //do whatever menu 1 is
case "menu 2": //do whatever menu 2 is
case "exit": //exit // save whatever
default: System.out.println("message not understood");
    }
}
```

This is a contains method. This should give you a strong indication on how to find an element in the linkedlist and how to delete it. (I'll leave this to you, as this is relatively easy and you need to learn).

```
public boolean contains(String str) {
Node ref;
while (ref != null)
    ref = ref.next;
    if (ref.data == str) {
    return true;
   }
return false;
}
```

Comment: Other notes: default constructors that set values you would access as null is bad. Set the data field to "" (empty string). In this case you can argue "well the Node class is private the user can't access it" well then why would you have a default constructor? Either change the default constructor or delete it. (Its just bad practice)